# Select query for laravel to get specific rows based on a condition at top remaining columns at bottom

Tags: php, sql, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel. I have a doubt about the Laravel select query. I am explaining my requirement here.

I want to select the total mark of all students in a school. But I have to get the marks of students in a specific order. Marks of 5A batch at the top and after that marks of other batches. Marks of all batches are stored in the table "total_marks" in a random manner. This table has the columns "student_name", "batch", "total_marks"

So help me to get the select query for this situation.

Comment: To make things easier, post your table and and example of the result that you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A plain mysql query will look something like

```
select *
from table
order by case 
          when batch = '5A'
          then 0
          else 1 
          end, total_marks desc
```

Or

```
select *
from table
order by batch = '5A' desc, total_marks desc
```

In laravel i guess it can be written as

```
DB::table('yourtable')
    ->orderByRaw("case when batch = '5A' then 0 else 1 end, total_marks desc")
    ->get();
```

or

```
DB::table('yourtable')
    ->orderByRaw("batch = '5A' desc, total_marks desc")
    ->get()
```